# XML Filter Expression for WFS download using Interoperability Connection Extension in ArcGIS Desktop

Tags: arcgis-desktop, wfs, filter, xml, data-interoperability

I need to download features from [this](https://fbinter.stadt-berlin.de/fb/wfs/data/senstadt/s_Fahrbahnmarkierung_Linie?service=WFS&request=GetCapabilities&acceptversions=2.0.0&) WFS but there are too many features for the server to handle my request. So I thought I should filter my request using the XML Filter Expression Editor. However I cannot find any information on how to write such an expression into the editor.

I only need features with the attribute "FBL" having the value '8' (it is a string and not a numerical field).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
https://fbinter.stadt-berlin.de/fb/wfs/data/senstadt/s_Fahrbahnmarkierung_Linie?service=WFS&request=GetFeature&typenames=fis:s_Fahrbahnmarkierung_Linie&version=2.0.0&Filter=<Filter><PropertyIsEqualTo><PropertyName>FBL</PropertyName><Literal>8</Literal></PropertyIsEqualTo></Filter>&resultType=hits&
```

Tells us the query will give **41381** results, so you'll probably need to add some paging, like:

```
https://fbinter.stadt-berlin.de/fb/wfs/data/senstadt/s_Fahrbahnmarkierung_Linie?service=WFS&request=GetFeature&typenames=fis:s_Fahrbahnmarkierung_Linie&version=2.0.0&Filter=<Filter><PropertyIsEqualTo><PropertyName>FBL</PropertyName>%20%20<Literal>8</Literal></PropertyIsEqualTo></Filter>&startindex=0&count=5&
```

then

```
https://fbinter.stadt-berlin.de/fb/wfs/data/senstadt/s_Fahrbahnmarkierung_Linie?service=WFS&request=GetFeature&typenames=fis:s_Fahrbahnmarkierung_Linie&version=2.0.0&Filter=<Filter><PropertyIsEqualTo><PropertyName>FBL</PropertyName>%20%20<Literal>8</Literal></PropertyIsEqualTo></Filter>&startindex=6&count=5&
```

etc.

You'll need to work out how many results you can fetch at a time

Comment: thanks @nmtoken! I can fetch 50000 features but I have no idea how to use it with the ArcGIS interoperability tool and its inbuild XML Filter expression feature. Pasting in your URL code does not work but I didnt expect that. I am not a coder

Comment: @jpg Did you paste just the filter from the request `<Filter><PropertyIsEqualTo><PropertyName>FBL</PropertyName><Literal>8</Literal></PropertyIsEqualTo></Filter>`

Comment: I did it withouth <filter> because I thought this should come automatically in a feature called "filter expression". But there is no way to see the actual query sent by the inteoperability tool. Anyway, it worked with the code you posted in your above comment. Thx a lot!